# Derivate by parameter or by initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Denote in $y(x, τ, ξ)$ solution to the Cauchy problem:
$$y' = −y + (x − 3)(1 − e^{−y}),  y(τ) = ξ$$

Find:
$$\frac{∂y(x, 2, ξ)}{∂ξ}|ξ=0$$

How to do it? Any notes?

Comment: A routine question asked is about your trial or difficulty faced.

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Comment: Try differentiating the equation and initial condition by $\xi$ then solving the resulting Cauchy problem for $y_\xi$

Comment: After that? Any notes?